# Android ADT loading data for Android 4.4.2 all the time

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Kepler SP2 with the latest ADT plugin. Every other minute Eclipse is saying 'Loading data for Android 4.4.2' and blocks everything I want to do. I am trying to work on project with Android `4.2.2` but I can't, here are 4 things I did:

- Windows > Android Virtual Device Manager, and it shows me the target with "Target Name" is `4.2.2`
- Windows > Preference > Android and I clicked on `Android 4.2.2` then "Apply > OK" but its still shows me that I'm using `4.4.2`
- Right click on my project, selected Properties > Android (on the left) and there was three, `Android 4.2.2`, Google APIs and `Android 4.4.2`, I checked `Android 4.2.2`, no use
- activity_main.xml > Graphical Layout, at the top middle window (about) there is Android green with a name "Android version to use when rendering layout in Eclipse" I want to change to `4.2.2` but its not there... on that Android green form there is number 19, when I open it, there are only 2, "Automatically Pick Best" and `Android 4.4.2`.
- I update my android ADT to `22.6.2`

Here my problem:

[image]

Here my ADT info. I tried to update it at all but it can't help...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the .android folder in your user directory and delete the cache folder. Solved the problem for me